# What do I do when Emacs is frozen?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, quitting, frozen-emacs

What should I do when Emacs stops responding?

My current "emacs-is-frozen" protocol looks like this:

- Spam `C-g` (it sometimes works)
- Wait for a while.
- `pkill -9 emacs`

What alternate steps could I try to avoid losing work that hasn't been autosaved yet?

If anything, could I attach GDB to know what the likely issue is?

Comment: Could it be that emacs hangs in an uninterruptible system call? I think not, for then even kill -9 might not help … but that could depend on the OS, so I am throwing the suggestion out there anyhow. In my experience, NFS problems are the most likely culprit. Try to access a file on an NFS filesystem where the server is down or inaccessible, and you're stuck. You should be able to see that in the flags column of a ps listing (consult the man page).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen kill -9 generally works :)

Comment: Attaching GDB certainly *is* an option. If you do that from the source directory (specifically, the `src/` subdirectory) and allow gdb to source the `.gdbinit` there, you'll get bonus commands (xbacktrace, etc.) for inspecting emacs internal structures (but the usefulness decreases dramatically if you have an optimized build, e.g. a release). See the `etc/DEBUG` file in the emacs tree for more information on debugging emacs.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When `C-g` doesn't work, you can sometimes get control back with:

```
pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs
```

As @Archenoth points out, sending the `SIGUSR2` signal to Emacs turns on debug-on-quit. This can be useful, but you'll want to turn it off again at some point (possibly immediately). To do this, call `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`.

More information on using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are found in the elisp manual, particularly [(elisp) Misc Events](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Misc-Events.html#Misc-Events) and [(elisp) Event Examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Event-Examples.html#Event-Examples), with related discussion of debugging in [(elisp) Error Debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html#Error-Debugging).

Comment: I don't, personally, remember a time when this didn't work. The signal handlers in Emacs exist at a very low level.

Comment: @PythonNut I probably have an Emacs freeze (neither C-g or SIGUSR1 work) about once a month. It's not supposed to happen I know, I assume there's some horrible interaction between multiple packages and my OS. I can't reproduce it reliably enough to try debugging :/

Comment: I've tried this extensively over the last few months. Works nicely in most cases, though in some it still fails.

Comment: Beautiful! It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: `pkill -SIGUSR2 -i emacs ; emacsclient -e '(setq debug-on-quit nil)'`

Comment: In my case (OSX) I had to do "pkill -SIGUSR2 Aquamacs" followed by "pkill Aquamacs" to get the desired behavior.

Comment: Could I do the same approach for emacsclient like: `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacsclient`?

Answer (score 5):

It also sometimes helps to `abort-recursive-edit` with <kbd>C-]</kbd>.

Comment: AFAIK this usually won't help during a freeze because `C-]` is not treated specially (so there is no reason that it manages to get out of a freeze and any other command doesn't).