# How can I log output of debug into a file?

Tags: debug, logging, backtrace

I am `GNU Emacs 28.1.91` with [native compilation](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/speed-up-emacs-libjansson-native-elisp-compilation). Emacs freezes so often, where I am unable to find what's is wrong. During the freeze all my work is always gone where the save does not occur.

Following: [What do I do when Emacs is frozen? [duplicate]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21645/18414), I have done `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`. but when freeze happens I cannot see/reach `*Backtrace*` of the error. I have to restart the Emacs and I cannot reach the log :-(

Is possible to write the log the bactrace to a file?

Comment: Keep `*Backtrace*` visible in another frame?

Comment: I am using Emacs daemon when I keep *Backtrace* visible I cannot get back focus to the buffer I am working on.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: @phils `GNU Emacs 28.1.91` with native compilation

Comment: Can't you resize the frames and keep them both visible at the same time?

Comment: @NickD I have tired that but when I cannot do `M-x <funcname>` on a different tab, the focus switch into backtrace frame

Comment: Maybe forego native compilation for now? It may be too new to use on your "working" emacs session. Maybe use it only for playing around, testing and reporting bugs and revert to a "normal" Emacs for your work.

Comment: @NickD After countless tries I was able to capture a debug output related `jit-lock-force-redisplay` as follows: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/85e5222f3e01760f96b82b85f7929cbb?permalink_comment_id=4330313#gistcomment-4330313 // I am not sure would this help to find the problem.